# How to make C# socket client method `Socket.ConnectAsync()` wait for server if that method is called before server is listening on the endpoint?

Tags: c#, sockets, .net-core

In C# .NET, I'm attempting to avoid a race condition where a socket client tries to connect to an endpoint before a socket server is bound to & listening on that endpoint.

One way to accomplish this is, if the client attempts to call a `connect()` method before the server is listening on the endpoint, the client waits indefinitely until the server is listening.

Looking in [documentation on Named Pipes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.namedpipeclientstream.connectasync?view=netframework-4.8), I see that `NamedPipeClientStream.ConnectAsync()` method will "asynchronously connect to a waiting server with an **infinite timeout** period". Yes, that's what I want.

However looking in [documentation on Sockets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.connectasync?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_Sockets_Socket_ConnectAsync_System_Net_Sockets_SocketAsyncEventArgs_), using the `Socket.ConnectAsync()` method, there doesn't seem to be a way to set a timeout period. Writing a test program, I see that `EADDRNOTAVAIL` [(Linux error 99)](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/) is thrown if the client does in fact attempt to connect before the server is listening to the endpoint.

**Is there any way to make the `Socket.ConnectAsync()` method wait for a socket server to listen to an endpoint instead of just throwing an exception?**

Comment: Yes, catch the exception and retry to connect - maybe after a short delay